# Parsing JSON on google app engine (java)

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine

i use **org.json** library to work with JSON-data in my apps. But it seems that google app engine doesn't allow to use it, what's the best way to work with JSON on GAE-apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope [this](http://nadacode.com/2010/06/30/using-json-in-your-google-app-engine-java-app/) helps

you can also the google-json api [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: First link has rotten. Unless someone can provide its content, the answer is not useful now.

Answer (score 9):

I had the similar question a week ago and after comparing a number of Java JSON libraries (including JSonLIB and GSON) I have chosen [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome). Check other comparisons on StackOverflow, most of them would recommend Jackson out of the rest.

After two weeks using it on Google Appengine, I just love it. Not only it has more features than the other mentioned libraries, it is also much faster (see benchmarks [here](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/)). It is a Json engine in [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) which I would recommend as well if you want to do anything  Restful on Appengine.

It is stable and still actively developed, with version 2 has just been released couple of weeks ago.

UPDATE: [here](http://blog.iparissa.com/googles-app-engine-java/google-app-engine-jax-rs-jersey/) is a sample demo for using Jackson with GAE.

Comment: People considering using Jackson with AppEngine should also take a look at https://github.com/icoloma/jackson4gae/ to serialize AppEngine classes. (Fair warning: I'm the developer, but it still is a common need for GAE+Jackson projects)

Comment: The last sample link is rotten. The description is in the answer is unclear to me and I am unable to follow it.

Answer (score 2):

try Gson

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 1):

Use fast JSON is a very productive API. Jackson take too much code.

http://code.alibabatech.com/wiki/display/FastJSON/Home

https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson

Just copy the library into WEB-INF/lib folder and use the static methods of `com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON` like `JSON.toJSONString(object)`