# Best way to write a jSON API on Google App Engine

Tags: java, json, api, google-app-engine

I'd like to create a Java web application on top of Google AppEngine.

What is the best way to develop a REST jSON API?

Do I have to write from scratch a servlet that manages the jSON handling or there is a library or something like the SOAP support for web services?

Comment: This is way too vague. Please try to ask more specific questions that have more objective answers.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882082/rest-json-web-services-java-ee-framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write a servlet from scratch, use JAX RS, it is easy and simple
http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2010/02/create-and-deploy-jax-rs-rest-service.html

Comment: I opted for that solution using jersey

Answer (score 1):

Try RESTEasy. It has [superb docs](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html) and there [nice examples to be found](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/integrate-jackson-with-resteasy/). It integrates with Jackson which is IMO the best JSON lib for java.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jersey then you should have a look at Genson http://owlike.github.io/genson/.
It is a full databinding+streaming java<>json library. And as a bonus with jersey you only need to have genson in your classpath and voila! Everything shall work without any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087256/parsing-json-on-google-app-engine-java) might be what you're looking for.  (Gson should be able to both generate and parse JSON)

Answer (score 0):

After some research I think that using [jersey](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2727-deploy-java-restful-application-on-the-google-app-engine/) is a good